# jQuery.post() returning 405 error on IIS server

Tags: jquery, ajax, http, iis

I am using a simple jquery post request to read an HTML file from the server. The file exists and is directly accessible through the URL. It also works on my Linux server, but doesn't on my client's Windows server. Any clue as of why this is happening? If it is a server setting, as in requiring additional headers, how would I correct it?

The code:

```
$.post('/ajax/about.html', function(data){
  $('.container').html(data);
});
```

The result as seen on Chrome's console:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405
>   (Method Not Allowed) http://example.com/ajax/about.html

But the file 'http://example.com/ajax/about.html' loads if typed directly into the address bar. (example.com is just a fake address used as an example, so it won't work)

Comment: You send POST, endpoint expects GET.

Comment: how to let the server know its a POST? I have no experience with IIS

Comment: If you want to read the file, then you probably just want to call $.get('/ajax/about.html')

Comment: It's static only for now. Soon it will be converted to a dynamic page. Then what to do?

Comment: Learn javascript, until its too late ;)

Comment: @BlackPanther anything accessing through addressbar in the browser is a Get request, so think about if you have enabled it at your serverside.

Comment: @c69 I know javascript. But I use jquery because it's allowed and I'll probably make my own wrappers otherwise. My question was simple. I know there are no syntax errors. So why is it not working? How can I get it to work? That's it

Comment: @Jai Its a server they usually use for other works. And they said they have used POST requests before, but may be not via ajax. It was a good point though

Answer (score 1):

A 405 is "Method not allowed" so I don't think the server is handling the post. 
To get a static resource, use GET.

Comment: It's not exactly a static resource. It's only the designing part that I do. The rest is done by the client gave the work. They use .Net

Comment: Plus, I don't think that is the problem. POST must be able to get static resources too.

Comment: A 405 is "Method not allowed" so I don't think the server is handling the post.